# Ruby file parsing x rows per record

Tags: ruby

I have a text file to parse. In this file, each record has content spread over a variable number of lines. The number of rows per record is not a fixed number. The content of the file looks like this:

```
ID\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
ID\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
ID\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
```

I want to slice it where there is a record in the first tab column (the ID column is empty in the following lines, so this way to determine a new record should work).

My current code for splitting it into chunks of five lines and then merging it:

```
f = File.read(file).each_line
f.each_slice(5) do | slice_to_handle |
  merged_row = slice_to_handle.delete("\n").split("\t").collect(&:strip)
  # Dealing with the data here..
end
```

I need to modify this to slice it as soon as there is an ID set in the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's Array inherits from Enumerable, which has [`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before), which is your friend:

```
text_file = "ID\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
ID\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent
ID\tcontent\tcontent
\tcontent\tcontent".split("\n")

text_file.slice_before(/^ID/).map(&:join)
```

Which looks like:

```
[
  "ID\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent",
  "ID\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent",
  "ID\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent\tcontent"
]
```

`text_file` is an array of lines, similar to what you'd get if you slurped a file using [`readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines).

[`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) iterates over the array looking for matches to the `/^ID/` pattern, and creates a new sub-array each time it's found.

`map(&:join)` walks over the sub-arrays and joins their contents into a single string.

This is not very scalable though. Using it, you'd be relying on being able to slurp in the entire file into memory, which can stop a machine in its tracks. Instead, it's better to read the content line-by-line and break the blocks and process them as soon as possible.

Comment: I interpreted that the `"ID"` in the question was just a place holder, which actually varies in the real example. I doubt that the OP meant literal strings `"ID"` and `"content"`.

Comment: ID could vary, as long as it's something that can be captured by the regex. I took it to mean a numeric field followed by a number of wrapped tab-separated values that had been wrapped as a result of being transmitted via email or some similar transport, which I've encountered in the past. Changing from `/^ID/` to `/^\d+/` would work equally well.

Comment: `/^\d+/` could be a possibility depending on what OP has, but a more general solution would be `/^(?!\t)/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.read(file)
.split(/^(?!\t)/)
.map{|record| record.split("\t").map(&:strip)}
```

Result

```
[
  [
    "ID",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content"
  ],
  [
    "ID",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content"
  ],
  [
    "ID",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content",
    "content"
  ]
]
```